# Communicate with launching app from Google Hangout

Tags: web, cross-domain, google-hangouts

I'm launching a Google Hangout from my webapp. I want to pass some data from my webapp to the Hangout window, and then back to my webapp. I am currently able to pass data back to my server with an AJAX post from the Hangout window, however, I then have to send this to the launching browser from my server.

Is there a direct line of communication from my launching app to the Google Hangouts app? I'm pretty new to webdev, so this might be an obvious question.

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing you are trying to achieve here to get and post data from your hangout app and web application server, and you are already posting the data from hangout app to your webserver.You can write a route in your application the one running on your web server to return the data you are trying to fetch and again in your hangout app can make a ajax get action to get the required data in form of JSON or any required format, and grap the result in success callback of ajax.

example call:-

```
    $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url:'/your_route_on_web_application/to_return_the_requested_data',
            data : { any_data_you_want_to_pass: random_data},
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
// do anything you want to with the received data
            }
        });
```